# I am trying to execute "react-native run-android " command but it fails with the following errors

Tags: android

JS server already running.
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...

> Configure project :app
>   WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (28.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.2.1.
>   Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
>   To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools.
>
> Task :app:installDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.

  > com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
28 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 27 up-to-date
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Command failed: ./gradlew installDebug

Error: Command failed: ./gradlew installDebug
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:607:13)
    at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:627:13)
    at runOnAllDevices (/home/palash/Documents/Pentamine/testfile/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runAndroid/runAndroid.js:299:19)
    at buildAndRun (/home/palash/Documents/Pentamine/testfile/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runAndroid/runAndroid.js:135:12)
    at isPackagerRunning.then.result (/home/palash/Documents/Pentamine/testfile/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runAndroid/runAndroid.js:65:12)
    at 
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)